# Preserving branches in private git repository

Tags: git

We have a git repository that collects all our company's private branches off of a public repository that comes from a project on GitHub.   We implement features that we don't want to push upstream, and those branches are typically based off of some tagged release from the public repository.

So far so good.  When I want to pull later revisions from the public repository, I use the

```
git fetch
```

command and then we can use those later versions to rebase our code on or implement other new branches.   However, if someone accidentally types the command:

```
git -p fetch
```

then our repository is purged of all branches that don't appear in the remote/origin.   Of course, none of are private stuff is up there so we could lose all or a chunk of our work that doesn't happen to be saved in one of our repository clones or a file system backup.

This seems like a very fragile situation that I would like to protect against.   Are we using the git facility in a way that it shouldn't be or is there some better way of doing this?

Comment: Fetch and prune will only remove tracking branches, which you can't edit anyway. If you've ever actually checked out the branch, then you'll still have a local branch pointing to the commit. Even if they're private branches on a public repo, prune won't remove them if you have proper permissions to the remote. Make sure you're authenticated, preferably with an ssh url.

Comment: @JeffPuckett The repository that I am discussing does not have a checkout -- it is a no-workspace repository meant to be cloned and to hold our private branches.  So the prune deletes those and that is what I am concerned about.

Answer (score 1):

By using the `git fetch -p` flag you're telling git to prune. I don't know what to say, you're actually directing it to do something destructive. Of course, with git, you can always use `git reflog` to walk back. Just check out the branch using the hash.

Comment: reflog is also removed at branch removal.

Answer (score 1):

`git` is not meant to be a backup replacement. However you are accurate with `fetch` it won't save you from storage failure.

Anyway, you can do 2 things:

- backup `.git/refs`, `.git/logs` directories and `.git/packed-refs` file. Reflogs unfortunately are deleted as you delete the branch, so you cannot rely on them.
- there is ["precious objects" extension](https://github.com/git/git/commit/067fbd4105c5aa8260a73cc6961854be0e93fa03), enable it as described there. Then objects are never collected and if you restore branches from backup you can be sure they are valid.

Comment: Of course we don't expect git to do a backup function.  Further, we do regular backups of the whole repository not just selected pieces of it.   The problem is that if someone accidentally does a purge it may not be detected for a number of backup cycles and that can make recovery difficult.   I would just rather have a bigger barrier to corrupting the data base anyway.